# Autostart Kodi on Vivid

Tags: 15.04, autostart, systemd, kodi

Ubuntu Vivid uses systemd, however I don't have a clue how it exactly works. Can maybe someone write the correct kodi.service file what needs to be placed in /etc/systemd/system
thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you just using this pc to run kodi? Or other background downloading services, nzbget, couchpotato. So forth?

Answer (score 3):

A more comprehensive guide.

#### Assumptions:

Starting with a naked Ubuntu Server; only SSH installed. Configuration done via SSH from another machine, not locally.

#### Install Kodi and pre-reqs:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xinit kodi
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel # If you need the Intel video package)
```

#### Create a kodi user & set groups:

```
sudo adduser --disabled-password --disabled-login --gecos "" kodi
sudo usermod -a -G audio kodi
sudo usermod -a -G video kodi
sudo usermod -a -G input kodi
sudo usermod -a -G dialout kodi
sudo usermod -a -G plugdev kodi
sudo usermod -a -G tty kodi
```

#### Reconfigure X11 to allow kodi to use it

```
dpkg-reconfigure x11-common # Change to Anybody
```

#### Create / Edit the Kodi Service

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/kodi.service
```

Should look like this: (via @SauliusZ)

```
[Unit]
Description=Job that runs Kodi
After=default.target graphical.target getty.target sound.target

[Service]
User=kodi
Restart=always
RestartSec=1s
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/kodi --standalone -- -nocursor

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

#### Reload and enable the daemon

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable kodi
```

#### Test Kodi

```
sudo service kodi start # should launch Kodi
sudo service kodi stop # should stop Kodi
```

Reboot to make sure it runs at boot

Comment: I did this, it seems quite too the point, and when I do ps aux | grep kodi I can see it there after rebooting, *but* in the TV there's an Ubuntu desktop login screen instead. :/

Answer (score 0):

I installed Kodi using [this guide](https://trick77.com/how-to-install-kodi-ubuntu-server-14-04/) on Ubuntu Server 15.04

And then by try and error came up with this.

```
[Unit]
Description=Job that runs Kodi
After=default.target graphical.target getty.target sound.target

[Service]
User=kodi
Restart=always
RestartSec=1s
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xinit /usr/bin/kodi --standalone -- -nocursor

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I am not sure about WantedBy part, but it works, and you're welcome to improve my code.